# Disabled button is not working every time

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

[image: This is my form]

This is my html update button code. updateItem is my method when I click on update this method will work.

```
(button start) 
button class="button" type="submit"  *ngIf="update" (click)="updateItem(dashboard.value)" [disabled]="formDate.untouched &&formTask.untouched &&formDescription.untouched">Update(button end)
```

this is my dashboard.component.ts file

```
edit(taskname:string){
       this.update=true;




       let fetchArray= JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('key'));

this.editItem = fetchArray.filter(fetchArray => fetchArray.taskname == taskname);


        this.taskname=this.editItem[0].taskname;

        this.date=this.editItem[0].date;
        this.description=this.editItem[0].description;
        this.updateval=this.editItem[0].taskname;


   }


  updateItem(form: any):void{

     this.update=false; 

       this.taskname=form.taskname;

       this.date=form.date;
       this.description=form.description;
       form.taskname=this.updateval;
       this.taskUpdate=form.taskname;

        let inLocalStorage= JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('key'));

          let itemUpdate={ "taskname":this.taskname , "date": this.date, "description": this.description};
          var j;



          for(var i=0; i< inLocalStorage.length; i++)
         {
           if (this.taskUpdate == inLocalStorage[i].taskname)
           {

             j=i;

           }

         }  

                 this.myArray.splice(j,1,itemUpdate);

             window.localStorage.setItem('key',JSON.stringify(this.myArray));

             this.match= JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('key'));



}
```

[when I click on edit button update button will show after click on update it will be disabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yv6Rf.png)

I want every time when I click on edit button update should be disabled

Comment: is it template driven from ? or reactive ?

Comment: can you please provide requested details, else it difficult to help you out, or please provide more code

Comment: please share your mail id if will send you complete code there. thank you

Comment: share it here : https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Actually code is too long and here is some limit. That's why i can't send here complete code

Comment: just share relavant code not full one, and let me know its reactive from or template driven , because lot depend on that

Comment: it's template driven form

Comment: ok can you show you html of that controls

Comment: added answer hope that helps

Comment: is that worked for y ou ?

Comment: no it's not working

Comment: hmm then to look your code my mail id is there in my profile

Answer (score 0):

as its template driven form then you should have html like as below

```
<input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.task" #formTask="ngModel" required>
```

if you have as above html then button tag will be like

```
button class="button" type="submit"  
 ..other code
[disabled]="!formDate.dirty && !formTask.dirty && !formDescription.dirty
```

check for `dirty` flag which tells you element modified or not and becuase `untouched`don't help much it just check you touched element or not.